# c# pictureBox, dynamic image, normally works fine

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox, gif

I have a simple problem and i can't work out what is going on, i have loaded generated images to picture boxes before with the same url structure with no problems, the below url is the location of my image but when i try picturebox1.load(url) it loads it no problem apparently but the imagebox shows no image, try blocks show it works fine.

If i browse to the url the image shows, if i use html to show the image with the url as src it works fine also...

What am i missing here?

Image location is:

http://www.thedemonsden.com/index.php?action=verificationcode;vid=register;rand=dd253984e86650be850ff83e24900251

Code:

```
pictureBox1.Load("http://www.thedemonsden.com/index.php?action=verificationcode;vid=register;rand=dd253984e86650be850ff83e24900251");
```

If i try something like:

```
richTextBox1.Text += pictureBox1.ImageLocation.ToString();
```

it shows that the location is indeed correct....

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your URL is bad, there is no image file there.  It is a HTML document with an img tag that is bad as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open http://www.thedemonsden.com/index.php?action=verificationcode;vid=register;rand=dd253984e86650be850ff83e24900251 in your browser.

Its a 1px by 1px image.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with other image with good resolution that should be atleast visible then check the application.